# aws lambda throws internal lambda error during streaming from kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, apache-camel-aws-kinesis

I am using lambda which uses kinesis stream as trigger . Below are the configuration of the trigger

```
Batch size: 100
Batch window: None
Concurrent batches per shard: 2
**Last processing result: PROBLEM: internal Lambda error.**
Maximum age of record: -1
On-failure destination:
{
  "onFailure": {}
}
Retry attempts: -1
Split batch on error: No
Starting position: LATEST
Tumbling window duration: None
```

After enabling the kinesis trigger in couple of hours I am getting error from lambda as **"Last processing result: PROBLEM: internal Lambda error."**

**FYI,My lambda processing logic:**

Lambda takes data from Kinesis

Performs few transformation

pushes data to power bi

I am suffering with this issue from couple of weeks , Any help highly appreciated pls

Comment: [This](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kinesis-data-streams-lambda-invocation/#:~:text=If%20your%20Kinesis%20data%20stream,producer%20must%20have%20proper%20access.&text=If%20the%20error%20is%20caused,an%20issue%20with%20stream%20processing.) AWS troubleshooting suggestion might be of use for you.

Comment: In comment it is told to as " If the error is caused by an internal Lambda function error, then this error indicates an issue with stream processing. To avoid control plane API throttling, restrict each stream to 4 to 5 event source mappings." In order to restrict stream to 4 to 5 event source mappings what should I do ?

Comment: or can I do something mentioned in below link what will be the impact if I configure provision concurrency? With this approach can I resolve the error ?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_console

Comment: this error showed up on my side and only lasted a few minutes, maybe refresh?